# Problem if 2 HTC Vive into field of view of emitters?

Tags: htc-vive

I am developing an app for a trade fair that uses the HTC Vive.

Now I am wondering how the HTC Vive syncs with the sensors...I suppose it uses bluetooth, are the sensors "coupled" with the glasses for example with a MAC-Address or sth like that, so another glasses will not work at all, before not configuring it?

I mean, if for any reason another glasses (connected to other computer but powered on) come into the field of view of the emitters, could it be a problem?

Since I have no access at the moment for a second HTC Vive I can't just test it.

If someone has info regarding this it will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTC Vive synchronises with the emitters via the emitters giving a flash.

The emitters are kinda dumb (in an amazingly smart way), they give a flash to synchronise, then they scan a vertical line over the room, and then a horizontal line. Each one does that in turn.

All the sensors and intelligence is in the many IR sensors on the tracked devices. Given that the emitters don't need to be connected to the PC at all multiple should work fine.

Source: http://gizmodo.com/this-is-how-valve-s-amazing-lighthouse-tracking-technol-1705356768

Comment: Also a reddit source from someone who says it should work: https://www.reddit.com/r/Vive/comments/4o4gw3/can_you_use_two_vives_in_same_room_using_2_pcs/

Comment: So, if I understand it right, I can use 2 HTC Vives using only 2 emitters? Should  not be also any problem if I want to use only one, but 2 glasses (powered on but connected to diferent pcs) are on the field of view of the emitters but not near players play area, since the logic happens in the glasses? What I don't understand is,

Comment: Yes, the only requirement to use a device with vive position tracking is that *the device* can see 2 emitters. If other things can see the same emitter that... doesn't matter at all (the fact that you can see a thing doesn't change if I can see that thing... unless you're standing in the way)

Comment: ok, so I can use 2 devices or more with only 2 emitters. And if I am using the Vive and another device come into the field of view doesn't affect at all my experience. That are very good things. They have done it really good. Could I then use 2 devices to play on same pc and they see each other, like you can do online with avatars, etc but just offline, same pc, same game, for example a showroom created in Unity, where using the controllers you could point to position and for example discuss about some design or sth? That would be huge but at least I saw it only using the Microsoft Hololens